# How To Stop Multiple Modals From Popping Up On Multiple Clicks To The Same Button (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am working in asp.net and have a table with a button which renders a modal popup. If I click this button more than once it pops up multiple modals, which I do not want. I haven't done very much JavaScript in my career but have the following code. I think that the conditional logic I am using may not be necessary, perhaps there are some JavaScript functions that would better serve this purpose. This is the code, the .singleAction refers to the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isClicked = false;
    $('.singleAction').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isClicked = true) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            isClicked = true;
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }).done(function(){
        isClicked = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var isModalOpen = false;

  $('.singleAction').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (isModalOpen) {
          return;
      }
      else {
          isModalOpen = true;
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
  });

  // Some logic to set isModalOpen to false once the
  // modal is closed...
  // ...
});
```

Biggest thing wrong with your code was the if statement. You were assigning true rather than checking for equality. And in JavaScript, when checking the value of booleans just use the variable name. Check out Truthy/Falsey values in JavaScript. http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html